# Play Json map object keys

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

```
val json = Json.parse(jsonString)
(json \ "theme" \ "structure" \ "layers")
```

The layers json key is an object with keys sequentially numbered like

```
{0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}}
```

I don't know how many keys there will be or the schema of the keys only that my key im trying to retrieve in each one exists.

I can access them using

```
(json \ "theme" \ "structure" \ "layers" \ "0" \ "mykey")
```

but as there are sometimes hundreds of layers I need to be able to iterate over them programmatically and check the value of "mykey" in each.

Answer (score 0):

```
(json \ "theme" \ "structure" \ "layers")
  .get
  .as[Map[String, JsObject]]
  .map(x => (x._1, (x._2 \ "mykey").get.as[String]))
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Use `.get` is unsafe/a bad practice, as for `Option` or `Try`